# casperjs waitfor behaving mysteriously

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to test a flow

```
1.Ajax Request      > Loader is visible

2.Response Received > a.Loader is hidden
                      b.Redirect to another page(where a interstitial is visible)
```

White testing them with casperJS I use the waitFor method, something like this.

```
   casper.waitFor(function check() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            return $("#loader").is(":hidden");
        });
    }, function then() {
        this.test.pass("Ajax request");
        this.waitDone();
    }, function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
        this.echo("Timeout: page did not load in time...").exit();
    },4000);
```

The thing is even if the condition is passed in `check`, `then` is not executed until the page is not redirected(read the flow, I am trying to test) and the test suite won't move to the next step.

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your reference 'this' is located within a casper block:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.waitFor(function check() {
```

Possible quick fix without knowing more detail.  Pass jQuery variable to evaluate.

```
this.evaluate(function($) {
```

You could also try:

```
casper.waitWhileVisible('#loader', function() {
    // executes when #loader is hidden
});
```

docs located at: [CasperJS waitWhileVisible](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitwhilevisible)